# Is it possible to add if statements when calling objects obj->sub1({if(foo==true) return foo; else return bar})?

Tags: php, object, if-statement

I'm trying to create an `if` statement inside `$soap` object, while typing its params.

My need is like that:

```
$soap->add($name,$something,$foo,$optionalarg,$optionalarg2);
```

This itself isn't too bad, but I need to change `$optionalarg` for something else (to be precise "brak" ("none" in polish) ).

Making lots of cases doesn't seem like good idea in that situation (it would be ton of that, and its not proper way to do that, I guess).

I know I could in theory prepare if for each optional arg before `$soap`, but I'm looking for alternatives.

I tried googling,

I tried doing random-ish things (sometimes stuff just works but not in this case), like

```
$soap->add($name,$something,$foo,{if($enabled==true) $optarg else "brak"})

$soap->add($name,$something,$foo,{if($enabled==true) return $optarg else return "brak"})

$soap->add($name,$something,$foo,if($enabled==true) $optarg else "brak")
```

everything was throwing errors, so I gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the ternary operator:

```
$soap->add($name, $something, $foo, $enabled==true ? $optarg : "brak");
```

or in this specific case:

```
$soap->add($name, $something, $foo, $enabled ? $optarg : "brak");
                                    ^^^^^^^^ evaluated / cast to boolean
```

It takes 3 arguments and returns the second argument if the first evaluates to `true` and the third if the first argument evaluates to `false`.

Comment: I catched 2 (4 actually but i broke 2 things by accident when modyfing) errors that way, tried it. my errors are "expected" and what it expects: semicolon and statement in phpstorm IDE though that seems to work, thanx :)